# What is the MSMQ-Container feature and why doesn't it exist on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: msmq, dism

I'm trying to script the setup of a web-server role for our application using PowerShell & dism.
The application requires the following features for MSMQ support (excluding IIS features for brevity):
* MSMQ-Container
* MSMQ-Server
* MSMQ-ADIntegration
* MSMQ-HTTP

I can install these features using dism /Online /Enable-Feature:xxx fine on Windows 7 but when I try to install MSMQ-Container on a Windows 2008 R2 machine I get the following error:

> Error: 0x800f080c
>
> Feature name MSMQ-Container is unknown.

If I leave it out then the rest MSMQ of the features install correctly on Windows 2008 R2, but then the script fails on Windows 7 with this error:

> Error: 50
>
> The operation completed but MSMQ-Server feature was not enabled.
>   Ensure that the following parent feature(s) are enabled first. If they are already enabled, refer to the log file for further diagnostics.
>   MSMQ-Container

*I guess the question is, what is **MSMQ-Container** and do I need it?*

If not, then I guess I'll need customise the script to use different packages on W7 and W2k8r2..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog by the MSMQ product group may help:

"Automate Your MSMQ Installation"
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/motleyqueue/archive/2007/10/20/automate-your-msmq-installation.aspx

which says

- MSMQ-Container on Vista doesn’t actually represent a component or service by itself, so installing it won’t do much for you. At the same time, trying to install just MSMQ-Server won’t get you where you’re going, either. If you want just the very basic MSMQ server functionality, you need to install MSMQ-Container and MSMQ-Server together.

Comment: I'm a little confused how this answers the question. If "Feature name MSMQ-Container is unknown" how does one install it as a prerequisite for MSMQ-Server?